# ReactJS: Why isn't className within id being referenced correctly for .scss?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have an scss file set up for a component like so:

```
#footer {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;

  .image-one {
    width: 50;
    height: 50;
  }
}
```

And in my component:

```
  render(){

    return(
      <footer id="footer">
        <img
          className="image-one"
          src="/files/img/imageOne.png"
        />
      </footer>
    )
  }
```

The footer is correctly referenced by the scss yet the `className="image-one"` is not. There is no change to the image-one. Am I doing it correctly?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Before padding:

[image]

After padding - Scroll bar appears:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you take `.image-one` out of `#footer { ... }`? Does it apply the css correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define a unit `(px / em / %)` to the values in your css/scss/sass file. The following should work...

It's the problem with your `scss` not `react`.

```css
#footer {
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.image-one {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"> </div>

<script type="text/babel">
ReactDOM.render(
        <footer id="footer">
        <img
          className="image-one"
          src="http://r.ddmcdn.com/s_f/o_1/cx_633/cy_0/cw_1725/ch_1725/w_720/APL/uploads/2014/11/too-cute-doggone-it-video-playlist.jpg"
        />
      </footer>,
        document.getElementById('example')
      );
</script>
```

Comment: cannot believe I missed it. One more quick question before I accept the answer and upvote. With px I tried doing `padding: 15px;` but the image-one went off the page with scroll.

Comment: I wanted to do `padding: 15px` inside the footer rather than pushing the image-one in, it went outside and the side page scroll appeared.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box` didn't do anything

Comment: checking to see if you've seen the comment. Let me know

Comment: Can you share me a fiddle or a pen to understand it better. Thanks!

Comment: it's set up exactly as in the original post. The image-one sits in the upper left corner inside the footer with the original set up so want to give it some padding (space) so it does not touch the borders of the footer. Sorry not used to fiddle/pen

Comment: I need a working demo. Can you set it up in a fiddle or a pen so that everyone understands your problem in detail. Thanks!

Comment: It is exactly how I said and provided. Not too difficult to understand. Trying to just adding padding inside the footer so the image inside the footer isn't touching the border of the footer, giving the image and footer itself some space. I don't know how to use fiddle/pen. Was going to upvote and accept the answer, but I guess I'll just ask elsewhere

Comment: I added screenshots in the original post. When I do not do padding, it is stuck in the upper left corner, the image-one pink box, but if I do padding, the scroll bar appears and everything is moved rather than just pushing in the elements inside.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123520/discussion-between-pranesh-ravi-and-ly-maneug).

Answer (score 0):

You missed unit for the `width` and `height` for the class `image-one`